# Runing AMPL file with CPLEX

Tags: optimization, cplex, modeling, ampl

I have an AMPL file and CPLEX software and I dont know if I can run it with CPLEX if yes How can do it? do I have to install something with CPLEX

NB: I dont have AMPL software

Answer (score 0):

You need access to AMPL to use AMPL. See https://ampl.com/ for some of the available options and licenses. Some of the licenses are free. You can also submit AMPL jobs to NEOS at https://neos-server.org/neos/.